# Turn off LCD touch screen on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: touchscreen, windows-iot, screen, windows, c#

I am using 7" touch screen on my RaspberryPi 3 Model B v1.2. My device is running Windows 10 IoT Core and I've designed the kit to run an application I am developing as a UWP application with interface. However, I've realised the screen never goes to sleep and I actually want it to go to sleep after X amount of time. There's this screen saver mode on IoT Core settings but it literally is only screen saver. Is that even possible at all, to make the display go to sleep? I am willing to do it on the application level as well, if possible at all.

I am new to Raspberry world so go easy on me!

**Edit: The touchscreen is the official Raspberry Pi 7" touch screen.**

Comment: what touch screen, specifically?

Comment: @pandalion98 official raspberry pi 7" touch screen

Comment: So after waiting for days and researching in the meantime and coming up with nothing, I am assuming there's literally no way to do this? Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search, it seems that, in theory, it *might* be possible to control the RasPi touch screen brightness.

Apparently, the I2C interface on the touch screen module is exposed. It seems that there's some need to poke around to determine the correct address, and the correct values to send.

The details are too scattered, so I'll just post the link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=152495

Comment: Oh yeah, there's no proper documentation on this feature (if at all), so the usual disclaimers apply (e.g. I'm not responsible if thermonuclear war arises because of this answer).